# How can I have additional favorite tags suggested?

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

I like using the favorite tags feature on Travel.SE, but I suspect there's some tags that I like but I haven't added yet. For example, as of today, I [frequently](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/324/andrew-grimm?tab=tags) ask about "local-customs", but don't have it as a favorite tag, and likewise for "hot-springs" and "kansai" (a region in Japan, which I do have as a favorite tag).

Approaches I can think of, and why there's problems with them:

- If I see an interesting question, and it isn't highlighted as having a favorite tag, and it has a tag that's interesting to me, add it as a favorite tag: one problem is that I partially use the highlighting of questions to find questions that are interesting to me, rather than looking at all of the questions. There's a lot of visa questions on there which I find boring.
- Look at my [tags page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/324/andrew-grimm?tab=tags): there's no indication of which tags have already been categorized as favorite or not. So for each tag on that page, I have to then scan my existing favorite tags to see if it's included. Also, some of the tags are just based on a single answer that got a lot of reputation, such as "i94" having [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10252/whats-the-value-of-the-genocide-and-similar-questions-on-the-us-immigration-f/10254#10254).
- Look at questions I've asked, and see which ones aren't highlighted: there's no highlighting of a [list of questions I've asked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20is%3Aquestion) ([or here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/324/andrew-grimm?tab=questions))

Answer (score 4):

There may be better options for what you want to do but I just want to comment on your second point regarding the [tags page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/324/andrew-grimm?tab=tags)...

That page *does* show if the tags are in your favorites or not. It's only shown when hovering over the tag so you do need to actively look at each individual tag, but that is a lot better than scanning a completely separate page. It also shows (on the right hand side of the tag) the total number of posts in that tag too (so having disproportionate score from a few posts doesn't matter—just look at the number of posts instead of the total score).

An example from my profile... I have [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography) as one of my favorite tags. So the star in the tag's tooltip is highlighted (you can also click the star to toggle any tag's favorite/ignored status). You can also see to the right of the tag that I have 46 posts in the tag.

> [image]